# ....Let $X_n \to X$ a.s and $E[X_n]=4$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_n \to X$ a.s and $E[X_n]=4$, for $n = 1, 2, ...$ . Then always $E[X] = 4$.

Comment: Hardly, since the result is wrong.

Comment: You need more assumption for $X_n$ to make the result holds.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample:

$P(X_n=4n^2)=\frac1{n^2}$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-\frac1{n^2}$.

Observe that $X_n\to0$ a.s.